# How to change value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm analyzing a dataframe with timestamped data in a 5 minute interval (:05,:10,:15 etc). Some measurements were delayed a minute which I want to correct to be able to match this data with another dataframe (so for example '2010-11-12 10:16' should be '2010-11-12 10:15'.

My code so far:

```
for index, row in trafficdata.iterrows():
    text=row['periodStart']
    if text[15]=='1':
        text=text[:15]+'0'+text[16:]
    if text[15]=='6':
        text=text[:15]+'5'+text[16:]
    row['periodStart']=text
    print(row['periodStart'])
etc etc
```

The dataframe seems to be changed (the print command in the last line gives the altered timestamp), but when I save the dataframe to a csv-file the old values still exist.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: quick and dirty assign the dataframe to a new one... that will have the changes for output

Comment: you now assign to `row`, but this is a copy of a row. You have to assign to the dataframe itself, eg using `trafficdata.loc[index, 'periodStart'] = text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the dates datetimes then use the [datetime replace method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

```
import pandas as pd

my_times = ['2015-01-31 01:01:00','2015-01-31 01:05:00','2015-01-31 01:11:00','2015-01-31 01:15:00','2015-01-31 01:16:00',
            '2015-01-31 01:21:00','2015-01-31 01:25:00','2015-01-31 01:30:00','2015-01-31 01:35:00','2015-01-31 01:41:00',
            '2015-01-31 01:45:00','2015-01-31 01:50:00','2015-01-31 01:55:00']

my_vals = range(260)[::20]
data = zip(my_times,my_vals)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['my_times','my_vals'])
df.my_times = pd.to_datetime(df.my_times)

def min_replace(x):
    if x.minute % 5 != 0:
        new_minute = int(round(x.minute/5.0)*5)
        x = my_time.replace(minute = new_minute)
        return x
    else:
        return x

df['my_times'] = df['my_times'].apply(min_replace)
```

Transforms:

```
              my_times  my_vals
0  2015-01-31 01:01:00        0
1  2015-01-31 01:05:00       20
2  2015-01-31 01:11:00       40
3  2015-01-31 01:15:00       60
4  2015-01-31 01:16:00       80
5  2015-01-31 01:21:00      100
6  2015-01-31 01:25:00      120
7  2015-01-31 01:30:00      140
8  2015-01-31 01:35:00      160
9  2015-01-31 01:41:00      180
10 2015-01-31 01:45:00      200
11 2015-01-31 01:50:00      220
12 2015-01-31 01:55:00      240
```

Into:

```
              my_times  my_vals
0  2015-01-31 01:00:00        0
1  2015-01-31 01:05:00       20
2  2015-01-31 01:10:00       40
3  2015-01-31 01:15:00       60
4  2015-01-31 01:15:00       80
5  2015-01-31 01:20:00      100
6  2015-01-31 01:25:00      120
7  2015-01-31 01:30:00      140
8  2015-01-31 01:35:00      160
9  2015-01-31 01:40:00      180
10 2015-01-31 01:45:00      200
11 2015-01-31 01:50:00      220
12 2015-01-31 01:55:00      240
```